# Keras LSTM index order (ascending or decending) and seeing string attached to 1 in binary classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

When doing an LSTM should the datetime index be ascending or decending? What I mean is should the head of the dataset be 2014 and the tail 2020 or the other way around? The reason I'm asking about this is because of the LSTM lookback period, I'm afraid that if it is not sorted correctly, then it will look into the wrong timeframe.

My current timeframe index when doing print(df) looks like this:

```
2014-21-3 XYZ
2014-22-3 XYZ
2014-23-3 XYZ
```

Should it be changed to this order instead for the LSTM to "work"?

```
2014-23-3 XYZ
2014-22-3 XYZ
2014-21-3 XYZ
```

Also when I am loading in a dataset which has a binary response variable that fluctuates between the two strings "Up" and "Down".
When doing a keras model it will output probabilities for the 1 value, however how do I know which string is 1 and which is the 0?

Also if the answer is do predict_classification then I'm sorry, that's not what I'm looking for here (just a heads up, since I've seen similar questions with that answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must use increasing order...

```
2014-21-3 XYZ
2014-22-3 XYZ
2014-23-3 XYZ
```

**EDIT (how to interpret probabilities)**:

you can encode Up as class 1 and Down as class 0

```
label = ['up','down','up','up','down']

map_label = {'up':1,'down':0}

[map_label[l] for l in label]
# ===> [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

you have two choices on how to interpret the output of a classification problem. it depends on the activation output you choose (sigmoid or softmax)

the sigmoid activation function is used to generate probabilities in binary classification problems. in this case, the model output an array of probabilities with shape equal to the length of the sample to predict. we can retrieve the predicted class simply checking the probability score... if it's above 0.5 (this is a common practice but u can also change it according to your needs) the sample belongs to the class 1 else it belongs to the class 0. in case of sigmoid, your last output layer must be `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')`

```
n_sample = 10
timestemp = 5
n_features = 3
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n_sample, timestemp, n_features))
y = np.random.randint(0,2, n_sample)

inp = Input((timestemp,n_features))
x = LSTM(8, activation='relu')(inp)
out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)

model = Model(inp, out)
model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy')
model.fit(X,y, epochs=3)

preds = model.predict(X) # (n_samples, 1)
y_classes = ((preds > 0.5)+0).ravel() # Up == 1 and Down == 0
```

in the case of softmax, the predicted class are retrieved using `argmax` and your last output layer must be `Dense(n_classes, activation='softmax')`

```
n_sample = 10
timestemp = 5
n_features = 3
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (n_sample, timestemp, n_features))
y = np.random.randint(0,2, n_sample)

inp = Input((timestemp,n_features))
x = LSTM(8, activation='relu')(inp)
out = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model(inp, out)
model.compile('adam', 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit(X,y, epochs=3)

preds = model.predict(X) # (n_samples, n_class)
y_classes = np.argmax(preds , axis=1)  # Up == 1 and Down == 0
```

I remain at disposal

Answer (score 1):

The future/present depends on the past but not the other way around. The LSTM cell to make a current prediction will use the memory from the past. For this reason the date should be in increasing order.

Part 2:

Since you have two possible labels `Up` and `Down`, you will have to put a linear layer of size 1 (or a multi layer neural network with its last layer being of size 1) over the output of LSTM. You can encode `Up` as class 1 and `Down` as class 0. When you train the model, each time-step will result in a single prediction and based on it value you can interpret it as 1 (`UP`) or 0(`Down`)

Sample:

```
import numpy as np

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, TimeDistributed
from keras.layers import LSTM

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(8, input_shape = (10, 1), return_sequences = True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1))) 
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

# 4 samples each of 10 timesteps with 1 feature each
X = np.random.randn(4,10,1) 
# Each timestep has a label 1 for UP and 0 for down
y = np.random.randint(0,2, size=(4,10, 1))

model.fit(X, y, epochs=2)
print (model.predict(X).shape)
```

Output:

```
Epoch 1/2
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 76ms/step - loss: 0.4758
Epoch 2/2
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.4704
(4, 10, 1)
```

As you can see the size of predictions is `4 X 10 X 1` i.e for each timestep for each sample it predicts the probability that it belongs to class 1. If you want to predict the class directly you can use

```
model.predict_classes(X)
```

Comment: Just to be sure, increasing order would be: 
`2014-21-3 XYZ
2014-22-3 XYZ
2014-23-3 XYZ`

The first code block I wrote in the post

Comment: Very well thank you, may I ask if you also hold the answer to the question in the bottom part of my post aswell?